# KVO for a singleton with multiple observers?

Tags: objective-c, ios, singleton, key-value-observing, nsnotifications

I'm currently contemplating whether to use KVO or NSNotifications to alert several objects in my iOS app when a property of my singleton has changed.

Since all the objects that need to be notified of the change has a reference to the singleton, KVO would seem like the natural solution. *However*, I've never used KVO with a singleton and multiple observers, so I don't know if that pattern is advisable or even possible.

Is it a good idea (or even possible) to use KVO on a singleton with multiple observers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other answers haven't answered the real questions, whether KVO works with multiple observers observing the same thing on a singleton.

Testing, however, shows that it works fine, and I haven't seen anything about the practice being wrong.

Answer (score 5):

Use NSNotifications when you can wait for the event loop.

Use KVO when you need immediate response to the change in state.

Answer (score 2):

Use KVO in this is feasible, as the underlying Cocoa Framework has support built-in to notify the observers and you need not re-invent the wheel